# Choosing a CMS: EPiServer vs Orchard vs SiteCore vs Umbraco

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, umbraco, orchardcms, episerver

Increasingly, I have noticed the number of Content Management Systems in use. I have some familiarity with SiteCore. I have read some literature on Umbraco. I only just got wind of Orchard the other day. I have only heard positive feedback about EPiServer. I am soon to move into a role that uses it.

Do these differ vastly in features and price? What has led you to choose one (or several) over the others?

**EDIT**

I did a brief review of so-called free CMSs here: [On Free Microsoft Compatible Content Management Systems](http://blog.philipcarney.com/post/16755851422/on-free-microsoft-compatible-content-management-systems)

Reasons I ditched Orchard when developing a 50k page website:

> The Orchard CMS import tool is simply too slow. It would only accept
>   small batches at a time. Initially, it took eight minutes to import
>   1000 records. So, working on that principle I expected that it could
>   take seven hours to import all the records. Unfortunately, I started
>   to receive performance issues as more records were inserted into the
>   database. I even started to reduce the batch size, which helped only
>   temporarily in the early stages. (*See* [Saying no to Orchard](http://blog.philipcarney.com/post/27252645475/the-beginning-of-carnotaurus-cms))

Comment: Orchard currently still has some glaring gaps in the out-of-the box experience (limited control over how to sort and filter lists of content, only text fields) but you can develop just about anything yourself on top of that and it's an amazing piece of work in how it's been architected so I feel it bodes well for the future from a purely developer perspective.

Comment: @rohancragg I took a look at Orchard CMS today. I like many of its features but what I dislike about it is that it does not have a content treeview in admin mode like both EPiServer and SiteCore have in edit mode.

Comment: Reasons blog is dead. Do you have an alternative link?

Comment: @Animesh Done :)

Comment: Appears to be Carney Code, Carnotaurus CMS, now defunct? If accurate, sad... I was hopeful, it piqued my interest a bit, especially learning about CMS stack scalability.

Comment: @MichaelW.Powell The short is that these are defunct. I dropped the research programme once I discovered that I could do everything that I needed by writing code for Umbraco 8 to walk the relevant tables and import it into Umbraco. It scales really well and is free.

Comment: Huh @PhilC well Umbraco v Orchard, an interesting comparison. Except for what looks like a lack of Postgresql support by Umbraco. Oh, and Umbraco appears to be more 'closed' then open source, perhaps freemium, with pricing models extending into production deployment. Otherwise, it does seem like a more firmly well established stack.

Answer (score 13):

I can only comment mainly on Sitecore and a bit on Umbraco from my knowledge of others using it:

**Sitecore** is an enterprise level web CMS with an "enterprise price tag." It's very extensible, has a lot of developer/community support, and is very developer friendly. The structure of content is based on a tree of nodes with parent-children relationships. Sitecore is well known in the WCM community as a leader in content management and is rated very well by companies sch as Forrester Research, etc.

Based on my previous research and conversations with friends, **Umbraco** is very similar to Sitecore. It has a lower price compared to Sitecore but its not a complete rip off. Umbraco is also built on ASP.NET like Sitecore.

[Here's a three-part series on Sitecore vs. Umbraco](http://web.archive.org/web/20130801034615/http://blog.created.dk/post/Sitecore-vs-Umbraco-e28093-introduction.aspx) from a developer.

Comment: I know StackOverflow hates links, but that 3-part comparison was incredible!  Thanks for posting the link.

Answer (score 6):

Of the ones you mention above, I have only used Umbraco and Sitecore to build with and am certified in both.  I like the way they allow me to build systems that really work well for my customers.  They both have a feel that they simply give you building blocks to create your masterpiece instead of "modules" of functionality plugged in that give you a blog, forum, etc.  They make it really easy to share content throughout the site and create really nice admin experiences.

Umbraco's community is really great.  They both struggle a little on the documentation side IMO, but Umbraco's videos really help and the community is quick to help.  Also, if you're talking cost then its free (Umbraco) vs. quite expensive (Sitecore).

But the reality is that each developer has their own taste and the style of CMS they like to work with.  Ultimately, its the team that has to build the site that really matters most when it comes to how each CMS performs for the end user.

In addition to the links above, here are a couple blog posts that may help you get a feel for the different systems:

[Orchard & Umbraco - Introduction](http://www.aaron-powell.com/orchard-umbraco) (part 1 of 4) - Aaron Powell

[Sitecore vs. Umbraco Terminology](http://www.proworks.com/blog/2009/07/15/sitecore-vs-umbraco-terminology/)

Good luck!

Comment: It starts around $10K and goes up from there.

Answer (score 4):

I mostly work with EPiServer and Sitecore, and I can tell you the difference in short:

- **Sitecore** has broader architecture and more powerfull UI. CMS is deeply configurable and highly extensible, it has clever publishing and caching system, powerful search and page editor. But it doesn't provide much out of box and UI is pretty old, slow and hard to learn. So this will be a long journey until you understand it good and make a good support of all its features for editors.
- **EPiServer** is easy, friendly to users and developers. It provides an essential bunch of features out of box, has easy UI and page editor, good drag-and-drop experience, easy personalization. It is code-first, distributed with NuGet, provides dependency injection for its services, out of box MVC support. But it's not so extensible and configurable, has pure search (without expensive EPiFind module) and generally lower-featured comparing to Sitecore. So it's good for small/middle websites, but can be an obstacle in complex solutions.

Both have similar tree-item concept, rich documentation, pure public module system and hard UI customization. Both expensive and not open source.

As I know, **Umbraco** is pretty similar to EPiServer and Sitecore, but free and open source. Of course you get less features, more bugs, not much docs and no free support.

**Orchard** is really different comparing to other three CMS. It is module-based like Wordpress: you use standard or public modules and themes, instead of writing the whole website from scratch. You create your own themes and modules to customize the website and CMS. So entire CMS is highly extensible and provides a lot of free community modules. But in the same time you lose control and learning curve is much longer. Orchard is free and open-source, entirely MVC-based, UI and API are well done, but it can be hard for both developers and editors to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress vs Episerver:

http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/2/comparison-of-episerver-and-wordpress/

OK so the guy who wrote that is an Episerver consultant but it's interesting and balanced.

Answer (score 1):

All the different web content management systems have different strengths. So which one is best for you depends a lot on what kind of sites you create, what kind of budget you have and what you think matters the most in a CMS.

For example, Orchard and SiteCore are VERY different systems.

I'm a bit biased as I work there, but I believe that [Webnodes CMS](http://www.webnodes.com) have several important advantages over the systems you mention.

Keywords: Relations between content, actual classes for the different content types, custom LINQ provider for all data access, expose all content as an OData endpoint etc.

Microsoft used our CMS to demonstrate OData at Mix11. [Video from Mix 11](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmEr87-NE40)